# How to swap radio button checked on click either by java script or by jquery ??? my code attached

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, radio-button

i have created radio button on run time its value,id and name are same like 1,2,3... and so on, but i wanna interchange its values like this,

http://jsfiddle.net/u8ySM/

radio button is shown as,

[image]

after page load it would be like this and when i change radio it change its radio checked with the previous one

i am trying it my code is here,

```
var selection=new Array(); 
 var allR = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var a=0;
  var b=0;
    for(var i=0; i<allR.length; i++){ 
        if(allR[i].type=='radio') { b++; }      
        if(allR[i].type=='radio' && allR[i].checked) { a++; } 
    }
var num=0;
alert(b);
    for(var j=1;j<=b ;j++)
{
//for(var i=0; i<alr.length; i++){ 
if(document.getElementsByName('j').checked)
{
selection[num]=j;
num++;
alert(j);
//}
}
}
```

here i am getting total radio button in "b" variable and then putting the checked radio in array but cant swapping radio checked ???

hopes for your suggestions

EDITED:

html code would be like this,

```
<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Accounts' value='1' id=1 checked='checked'>1

<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Accounts' value='2' id=2>2

<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Accounts' value='3' id=3>3
<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Accounts' value='4' id=4>4
<br/>
<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Analytical Question' value='1' id=1>1
<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Analytical Question' value='2' id=2 checked='checked'>2

<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Analytical Question' value='3' id=3>3

<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Analytical Question' value='4' id=4>4
<br/>
<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Behavior Questions' value='1' id=1>1
<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Behavior Questions' value='2' id=2>2
<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Behavior Questions' value='3' id=3 checked='checked'>3

<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Behavior Questions' value='4' id=4>4
<br/>
<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Technical Questions' value='1' id=1>1


<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Technical Questions' value='2' id=>2


<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Technical Questions' value='3' id=3>3


<input type='radio' onclick='test(this.id);' name='Technical Questions' value='4' id=4 checked='checked'>4
```

now how to swap in this radio checked values ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'swap radio button checked on click'. The event you should be using with radio, checkbox and select is change/onchange.

Comment: swap means if i click radio "4" to "2" then if there is any radio that is previously checked "2" then it would chnag it to "4"

Comment: If you could make a jsfiddle with your markup and js it would save us some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vdj4u/3/)

The code looks like this

```
    $(function() {
    var arr = {
        'Accounts': '1',
        'Analytical_Question': '2',
        'Behavior_Questions': '3',
        'Technical_Questions': '4'
    }
    $('input:radio').on('click', function() {
        var grName = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();
        // Set the arr value here
        var currCheck = $('input[value=' + value + ']:checked');
        $.each(currCheck, function() {
            if ($(this).attr('name') != grName) {
                var temp = $(this).val();
                var teGrp = $(this).attr('name');
                var teVal = arr[grName];
                arr[teGrp] = teVal;
                arr[grName] = temp;
                $('input[name=' + teGrp + '][value=' + temp + ']').attr('checked', false);
                $('input[name=' + teGrp + '][value=' + teVal + ']').attr('checked', true);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

[YOUR MARKUP FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BwnjG/)  -- Make sure the Name attributes have no spaces in between

Comment: @reddy is it fix for the html i gave you or it would work for general means i am creating radio on run time so it would work for that too? some time radio group will increase to 5 then it would have 12345 and so on for more or less

Comment: It  should work for any number of radiobuttons.. Just make sure you add the new namegroup to the arr object and it should be fine...

Comment: i am creating radio button at run time grp name means my new radio button name shoud be "grp5"? then what about Arr array you getting name name of radio button in it how would it get the fifth one radio name in it ??

Comment: one more thing how to use this code in my code means onClick function ?? what the name of this function ?i havent work with jquery

Comment: You don't need to add any click event to your HTML.. $('input:radio').on('click', function() {  assigns the click event to the radio buttons on the page... Just use this as  it is but make sure you include the jQuery .js file in the head tag of your page..<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  .. this should be good enough

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understand it right you wanted to do:
eg. if you click "2" in row1, you'd like to have "1" checked in row2.

I have prepared a working script for you,
take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/nb3j9/

Comment: is it fix for the html i gave you or it would work for general means i am creating radio on run time so it would work for that too? some time radio group will increase to 5 then it would have 12345 and so on for more or less radio button